# “The account sign-in was incorrect or your account is disabled temporarily. Please wait and try again later.”}

Tags: php, api, rest, magento, magento2

I have created a user in Magento for customer. I need to create a login api for customer.For that I need a token to use.To generate that I have used the below code which ended up in  the following error.

> {"message":"The account sign-in was incorrect or your account is disabled temporarily. Please wait and try again later."}

My code is as follows

```
    <?php

$userData = ["username" => "xxx@gmail.com", "password" => "xxx"];
$ch = curl_init("https://www.djbjsdjs.com/rest/V1/integration/customer/token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($userData));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Content-Lenght: " . strlen(json_encode($userData))));

$token = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($token);
```

Comment: If you look at https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-token.html you can see very simple curl based examples - try them before the PHP code to get a feel... I believe your issue relates to the way `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` is being passed - I don't think you need to pass the Content-Length value - rather its auto-filled by PHP

Comment: This solution works for me, i elimnated subdomains: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/321854/getting-error-the-account-sign-in-was-incorrect-or-your-account-is-disabled-te/322382#322382

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make call on /rest/default/V1/integration/customer/token instead of on /index.php/rest/default/V1/integration/customer/token.

Second, make sure you don't make call to mapped subdomains. For example if you mapped localhost or 127.0.0.1 onto mydomain.local in /etc/hosts, don't make call to http://mydomain.local/rest/default/V1/integration/customer/token, but on http://127.0.0.1/rest/default/V1/integration/customer/token